# Concurrent outbound HTTP Request in Node.js makes the response slower

Tags: node.js, express, http, concurrency, load-testing

I'm currently load testing one of my API (Node.js + Express). This API makes a HTTP request to another server. Here's an example code:

```
var start = new Date()
axios.get('https://google.com')
     .then(function (response) {
         var end = (new Date() - start)/1000
         console.info('Finished in %ds', end)
     })
```

During the test, I find out that the more concurrent HTTP requests to the other server (in this example it's google.com), the slower the response becomes. I use Apache Jmeter for testing.

For example, if I do 1 request in one second:

```
Finished in 0.150s
```

But if I do 100 requests in one second:

```
Finished in 0.320s
...
Finished in 1.190s
Finished in 2.559s
Finished in 1.230s
Finished in 5.530s
```

At first I thought there must be a problem in the other server but that is not the case, even after I changed it to google.com (as per example), the same thing happened.

The more outbound http request that node.js has to make, the slower the response becomes. I have tried to improve my API by using node cluster, the workers help but I want to improve the response time even further.

Is there anything that I can do? or perhaps an explanation on why does this happen? I thought since my API makes asynchronous http requests, there should be no blocking, thus the response time should not be increased by such a significant amount.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a larger context for your code so we can make sure you're timing things accurately?  Are you 100% sure that google.com is not rate limiting rapid requests all coming from the same source IP?  Your rapid test of 100 requests in a second probably looks like an attack underway.  Have you considered testing with 100 different URLs all to high scale sites, but all separate hosts to make sure there is no rate limiting by either the target or by your ISP?

Comment: What do you mean, you use Apache Jmeter for testing?  This looks like a stand-alone nodejs program that you just run by itself.  What roles does Apache Jmeter play in this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue - in my instance I was awaiting each API call rather than allowing them to all occur asynchronously.

To do this you can push all of your async API calls into an array. For example, if you need to call a series of urls:

```
const requests = []
urls = ['http...a/get','http...b/get']
urls.map(item => {
  request.push(axios.get(item))
})
```

Now that each of these calls are occurring asynchronously, be sure to wait for all of them to resolve before consuming the data.

```
const allAPIData = await Promise.all(requests)
```

Just be sure to handle your promise resolution in the event any of the API calls fail, perhaps with a helper function that nests `axios.get(url)`. Otherwise any failed API promises could cause issues awaiting and resolving the `Promise.all()` statement.